# Passing API (model class) to a widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to reuse my filter widget. The filter Widget use so far one API (or model class) with all the logic in it. To be able to reuse the filter widget I need to pass different API to it and I just can't find a way to to that. Here is part of my code for better understanding (simplified)

```
class FilterWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final DogFilter filter; //<-- I want also use this widget with CatFilter API and so on
                          // <-- How to make parameter which would take API

  const FilterWidget({this.filter});
  @override
  _FilterWidgetState createState() => _FilterWidgetState();
}

DogFilter _newFilter = DogFilter();
....
```

I tried this

```
class FilterWidget<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final T filter; 

  const FilterWidget({this.filter});
  @override
  _FilterWidgetState createState() => _FilterWidgetState<T>();
}
....
```

But then I didn't get access to getters and setters. I wasn't even able to create new instance

```
    T _newFilter = T(); // that doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to make an abstract class, lets say animal class with all getters and setters which you use in your filter.

```
abstract class AnimalFilter {
  get getWhatever;
  ...
}
```

Then implement all your classes (DogFilter, CatFilter) from that AnimalClass

```
class DogFilter implements AnimalFilter {
...
}
```

And after that use AnimalFilter class in your filter instead of Dog or Cat class

```
class FilterWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final AnimalFilter filter; 

  const FilterWidget({this.filter});
  @override
  _FilterWidgetState createState() => _FilterWidgetState();
}
```